# How to configure emacs drag and drop to open instead of append on osx

Tags: emacs

How to configure emacs 23.1.1 on osx so that file drag and drop on the emacs window opens the file in a new buffer instead of appending it to the current buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
(global-set-key [ns-drag-file] 'ns-find-file)
```

It works for me on Emacs 23.2.1

Comment: Almost, but not quite.  Add this to my ~/.emacs got it to stop opening up in the same buffer, but I want it to open up in a unique buffer in the same window.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850292/emacs-23-1-and-mac-os-x-problem-with-files-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
(if (fboundp 'ns-find-file)
    (global-set-key [ns-drag-file] 'ns-find-file))
```

This (which basically is the same as given in other answers) ensures that a new buffer is created. The `if` part ensures that the code will work even in a non-Mac environment.

```
(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)
```

This ensures that the new buffer is displayed in an existing window, so that a new Emacs frame isn't opened. (I noticed in a comment that you had trouble with this.)

Comment: Ahh, perfect!  This was really bugging me, but now my new mactop has emacs perfection, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I use in my .emacs:

```
; Upon drag-and-drop: Find the file, w/shift insert filename; w/meta insert file contents
; note that the emacs window must be selected (CMD-TAB) for the modifiers to register
(define-key global-map [M-ns-drag-file] 'ns-insert-file)
(define-key global-map [S-ns-drag-file] 'ns-insert-filename)
(define-key global-map [ns-drag-file] 'ns-find-file-in-frame)

(defun ns-insert-filename ()
  "Insert contents of first element of `ns-input-file' at point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((f (pop ns-input-file)))
    (insert f))
  (if ns-input-file                     ; any more? Separate by " "
      (insert " ")))

(defun ns-find-file-in-frame ()
  "Do a `find-file' with the `ns-input-file' as argument; staying in frame."
  (interactive)
  (let ((ns-pop-up-frames nil))
    (ns-find-file)))
```

Comment: Awesome!  These work great -- thanks so much!  Is it possible to change the default behavior of ns-drag-file, if the destination is a shell buffer?  In particular, if I drag into a shell, it seems natural for it to paste the full path.  But anyway, just curious.  Holding down shift is easy enough.